# How to compose BNF rules using Grammar-Kit

Tags: intellij-idea, bnf, ebnf, grammar-kit

I am trying to convert an EBNF file into working BNF for IntelliJ Grammar-kit.

In the EBNF there are rules as such:

```
BinOpChar ::= "~" | "!" | "@" | "#" | "$" | "%" | "^" | "&" | "*" | "-"
BinOp ::= BinOpChar, {BinOpChar}
```

How can I create such rules without resorting to regex? Reason being is that this kind of construct happens very often and it becomes repetitive to do in regex.

To be clear, I would like to be able to create a rule to match `@@` from `BinOpChar` but don't match `@ @`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to list each operator independently:

```
{
  tokens=[
    //...
    op_1='~'
    op_2='!'
    op_3='@'
    op_4='@@'
    op_5='#'
    //...
  ]
}
```

If you *really* want to accept all n + n^2 tokens, you will need to use a regular expression:

```
{
  tokens=[
    //...
    bin_op:'regexp:[~!@#]{1,2}'
    //...
  ]
}
```

But the idea is, you want to use the lexer to define tokens, and the grammar to define expressions and so forth. So in the grammar if you write:

```
{
  tokens=[
    space='regexp:\s+'
  ]
}

BinOp ::= BinOpChar [BinOpChar]
BinOpChar ::= "~" | "!" | "@" | "#"
```

Then it's going to accept `@@` and `@ @`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Weird, the last example you posted didn't work on Live Preview, I get:  `'~', '!', '@' or '#' expected, got '@@'`. Does intellij live preview work?

Comment: Sorry, the last example was a little confusing (the first expansion should be the root). Live Preview should now work verbatim in a `.bnf` file.

Comment: Thanks! '@ @' is not accepted for what I need, but mixing Tokens from regex seems to work, so I will mix from your suggestions. I really appreciate  your help